# How to draw circles around polygon/spider chart, without plotting libraries

Tags: r, polygon, r-base-graphics

Without using `ggplot2` or other plotting libraries, I would need to draw circles around a polygon/star chart vertices, i.e. each circle with a radius equal to the respective polygon radius. You can see an example here:

[image]

```
d1 <- 1:4
names(d1) <- LETTERS[1:4]
stars(matrix(d1,nrow=1),axes=TRUE, scale=FALSE,radius=TRUE, frame.plot=TRUE,labels = dimnames(d1)[[1]])
grid()[enter image description here][1]
```

I understand I should combine the `stars()` with the `symbols()`, `polygon()` functions or `par(...)` graphics, but honestly, I am new to these kind of plotting techniques and very lost on how to combine functions and arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any functions in base R that do circles for you, but you can concoct them manually.

```r
center <- c(x=2.1, y=2.1) # probably a better way
half <- seq(0, pi, length.out = 51)
for (D in d1) {
  Xs <- D * cos(half); Ys <- D * sin(half)
  lines(center["x"] + Xs, center["y"] + Ys, col = "gray", xpd = NA)
  lines(center["x"] + Xs, center["y"] - Ys, col = "gray", xpd = NA)
}
```

[image: stars with concentric circles]

Notes:

- I don't know off-hand how the center-point should be calculated, I chose that point using `locator(1)`; not being familiar with `stars`, there may be a better way to determine this programmatically and more accurately;
- The first `lines(.)` draws the upper semi-circle; the second draws the lower.
- The `xpd=NA` is to preclude clipping due to the drawing margin. It may not be necessary in your "real" data. See `?par` for more details on this.
- Though it may be difficult to detect here, the gray circles are drawn *on top of* the stars plot, which might be an aesthetic compromise. The only way around that is to plot the circles *first*. To do this, draw the first semicircle first with `plot(..., type="l")` and then add the remainder as expected, and only then run `stars(..., add=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves a lot of work so far. Wish you a great weekend ahead!

Comment: Thank you r2evans. I will surely do. I am trying to find a way to edit my question. Not sure if that is possible. I would like to add some more specifications to the question, if I am not being greedy. Would you advise that I post a new question?

Comment: Some editing is fine, but feature-creep/spiral-questions are discouraged. What are you trying to add?

Comment: Some pedantic job: adding the radii of the circles passing through all the vertices, adding the name labels at the end of the radii, outside of the circle and coloring the polygon area with some alpha....If packages were allowed, I would have probably found my way by now, but base R is k!ll!ng me. I think I might post a new question, sounds more appropriate. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think that's a fair way forward, thank you for understanding. Please don't forget to accept if/when this one is resolved.